# named does't start when using systemctl

Tags: systemd, timeout

I am having trouble getting named to start using systemd on the Fedora 18 Raspberry Pi spin. It starts, then a few moments later there is a timeout and it fails. If I run the commands in named.service by hand, named starts just fine. I don't know what the timeout is that systemctl is looking for or where it is being invoked. I have read the man pages for `systemctl`, systemd and others and I will continue to research this, but if anyone has any pointers, that would be great.

`systemctl status named.service` output:

```
named.service - Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
          Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service; disabled)
          Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Tue 2013-01-29 14:36:41 EST; 35min ago
         Process: 4189 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -u named $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
         Process: 4186 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z /etc/named.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
         Process: 4183 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/generate-rndc-key.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 29 14:35:12 raspi.example.com named[4191]: all zones loaded
Jan 29 14:35:12 raspi.example.com systemd[1]: PID file /run/named/named.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Jan 29 14:35:12 raspi.example.com named[4191]: running
Jan 29 14:36:41 raspi.example.com systemd[1]: named.service operation timed out. Terminating.
Jan 29 14:36:41 raspi.example.com named[4191]: shutting down
Jan 29 14:36:41 raspi.example.com named[4191]: stopping command channel on 127.0.0.1#953
Jan 29 14:36:41 raspi.example.com named[4191]: no longer listening on 127.0.0.1#53
Jan 29 14:36:41 raspi.example.com named[4191]: exiting
Jan 29 14:36:41 raspi.example.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS).
Jan 29 14:36:41 raspi.example.com systemd[1]: Unit named.service entered failed state
```

The named.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
Wants=nss-lookup.target
Before=nss-lookup.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/named
Environment=KRB5_KTNAME=/etc/named.keytab
PIDFile=/run/named/named.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/generate-rndc-key.sh
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z /etc/named.conf
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -u named $OPTIONS
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '/usr/sbin/rndc reload > /dev/null 2>&1 || /bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID'
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '/usr/sbin/rndc stop > /dev/null 2>&1 || /bin/kill -TERM $MAINPID'
PrivateTmp=true
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 8):

Answered.

This was the line:

> PID file /run/named/named.pid not readable (yet?) after start.

The (yet?) threw me. I thought the message was being thrown because it was trying to read the PID file before it was written out by named and since I didn't see an error after that, I figured it eventually read it successfully. Silly me for reading English. In fact, `named` writes the `pid` to `/var/run/named/named.pid`, which was not being read by `systemctl` (or systemd), ever.

Changed the PIDFile in `named.service` and it starts. Joy.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer. Had me stumped.

Comment: /var/run should be a symlink to /run...

Comment: Oh, Linux vagaries and one of the many annoying things about Linux distro and package development I loathe. /run is redundant when you have /var/run, which is where should be where variable things like pid files should go.

Comment: on my distro /var/run is a symlink to /run and this problem is still happening and I even edited named.conf i systemd and did not help.  There is another note on th is:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116725/pid-file-var-run-named-named-pid-not-readable-yet-after-start .  I figured out the directive

Answer (score 1):

```
systemctl enable named
```

is required before

```
systemctl start named
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... only error in the file the startup was:

```
systemd: Can't open PID file /run/named/named.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
```

I checked and my /var/run was symlinked to /run and I checked the /usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service and /var/run/named/named.pid was set.

I overlooked that in /var/named/named.conf the "pid-file" directive was there and it was set to "/var/named/named.pid".  I changed it to "/var/run/named/named.pid" and now it starts normally.

Answer (score -1):

Leaving this here for future reference, had a similar issue with named but with me the issue was due to too little ram being available.

figured this out by monitoring using: watch "systemctl restart named" , after some time noticed the memory usage spiked to the maxed allowed memory and then the service died.

Hope this helps someone in the future