# PID file /var/run/named/named.pid not readable (yet?) after start

Tags: fedora, systemd, bind

```
Feb 24 15:54:34 ns1 named[20308]: all zones loaded
Feb 24 15:54:34 ns1 named[20308]: running
Feb 24 15:54:34 ns1 systemd[1]: PID file /var/run/named/named.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Feb 24 15:56:03 ns1 systemd[1]: named.service operation timed out. Terminating.
Feb 24 15:56:03 ns1 named[20308]: shutting down
Feb 24 15:56:03 ns1 named[20308]: stopping command channel on 0.0.0.0#953
Feb 24 15:56:03 ns1 named[20308]: exiting
```

I have tried renaming to named.service as mentioned here: [named does't start when using systemctl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64573/named-doest-start-when-using-systemctl)

Comment: what does `ls -l /var/run/named/` show

Comment: @XTian `# ls -l /var/run/named/
          total 4
          -rw------- 1 named named 102 Feb 24 15:25 session.key`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks to be a bug. See this ticket titled: [Bug 984764 - bind-chroot-9.9.3-3.P1.fc19.x86_64 failed to start](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=984764).

The fix is to add this to your `named.conf` file:

```
pid-file      "/var/run/named/named.pid";
```

There are additional tips in the ticket with respect to getting your system back into a state where you can successfully run Bind afterwards.

Comment: This is still a bug in Centos 8 !

Comment: See this answer:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/763327/147316